# SonarQube @NoArgsConstructor (Project Lombok)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, lombok, sonarlint

I'm trying to use Project Lombok in my code and I'm using SonarQube and SonarLint (in IntelliJ IDEA).

When I create a new class with a private field like this:

```
public class Test {
    private String testfield;
}
```

then I get the correct warning from SonarQube/SonarLint "Remove this unused private field" (`squid:S1068`)... (So I know that the basic configuration is working.)

When I add the `@Getter @Setter` annotations to the field:

```
public class Test {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String testfield;
}
```

then the warning disapears (correctly!). (So I know that SonarQube basically understands Lombok annotations.)

And now when I create another Class like this

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

I get the warning "Add a private constructor" (`squid:S1118`)... (this is again correct and expected)

But when I now add the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation like this

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Test2 {
    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

the warning still remains.

Is this annotation not supported by SonarQube?
I've found this [JIRA issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-990) (and many discussions on stackoverflow, github, ...), and I think it should work.

(I'm using IntellIJ 2016.1.3; SonarLint 2.2; lombok 1.16.8; SonarQube 5.5; SonarQube Java Plugin 3.13.1)

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As of [SonarQube Java 3.14](http://www.sonarsource.com/2016/05/30/sonarqube-java-3-14-released/), in "[[SONARJAVA-1642](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1642)] - Filter issues related to Lombok annotations with a dedicated issue filter" there is support for annotating your classes with [`@lombok.experimental.UtilityClass`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass.html) without tripping that warning. `@NoArgsConstructor` may need a pull request.

([source diff](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/commit/34f7cfb372e3ae9b5ad5600047c46a801d94b1a7#diff-84ff76848a57911311adf938eec9b26dR60))

---

Lombok knows the `@NoArgsConstructor` but it only uses it to determine if a type is unused or not. It's not considered when checking for constructors of utility classes.

```
+  private static final Set<String> USED_TYPES_ANNOTATIONS = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
+    "lombok.Getter",
+    "lombok.Setter",
+    "lombok.Data",
+    "lombok.Value",
+    "lombok.Builder",
+    "lombok.ToString",
+    "lombok.EqualsAndHashCode",
+    "lombok.AllArgsConstructor",
+    "lombok.NoArgsConstructor",
+    "lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor"));
```

[pull-request](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/pull/102/commits/3f50c891e5bb210f56728ba0a7a884a79263b80f#diff-026580757732c4e01fcee4cb99cfa0abR83) for the ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already seen this pull request. Do you know if there are any plans to support this case by SonarQube?
Is there a better solution than annotate the class with `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1118")`?

Comment: @CptS see edit, I hope I didn't overlook sth this time.

Comment: That sounds great! I'll try that soon after upgrading the SonarQube Java Plugin.
Thank you! :)